# Access nested geojson data using the Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, geojson

I am using the Google Maps API with external json which looks something like this:

```
  {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            0,
            0
          ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "category": {
          "color": "#E91E63",
          "stroke-width": 1,
          "stroke-opacity": 1
        },
      },
    },
```

I'm trying to get to 'colour' like this

```
        map.data.setStyle(function (feature) {
          var strokeColor = feature.getProperty('color');
            return {
              strokeColor: strokeColor,
              strokeWeight: 3
            }; 
        });
```

But as it's nested in category and I'm not sure how to get to it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the `category` property, that returns an object with the properties defined in the GeoJSON:

```
Object
color: "#E91E63"
stroke-opacity: 1
stroke-width: 1
```

Get it in the style function like this:

```
map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
  var category = feature.getProperty('category');
  var strokeColor = category.color;
  return {
    strokeColor: strokeColor,
    strokeWeight: 3
  };
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/0ysa5prn/)

**code snippet:**

```js
"use strict";

let map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {
      lat: 0,
      lng: 0
    }
  }); // NOTE: This uses cross-domain XHR, and may not work on older browsers.
  map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
    var category = feature.getProperty('category');
    console.log(category);
    var strokeColor = category.color;
    return {
      strokeColor: strokeColor,
      strokeWeight: 3
    };
  });
  map.data.addGeoJson(geoJson);
}
var geoJson = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "LineString",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          0,
          0
        ],
        [10,
          10
        ]
      ]
    },
    "properties": {
      "category": {
        "color": "#E91E63",
        "stroke-width": 1,
        "stroke-opacity": 1
      },
    },
  }]
};
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Data Layer: Simple</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly" defer></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is almost working, but I'm getting an error:Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: category is undefined

Comment: The code snippet in my answer works.  What did you change in the `setStyle` function?  Is `category` still defined in your version?

Comment: Its exactly as your code. It does work as expected, however I am getting that error, which is causing another function (markers) to break.

Comment: What line are you getting that error on?  That error doesn't appear in the code snippet in my answer, I suspect the line generating it is something you added outside the scope where `category` is defined.  Can you provide a [mcve] that generates the error (jsfiddle or a new question with a Stack Snippet).

Comment: I think I'm getting this error becuase some rows don't have the category property. When it gets to a row without a category, everything else in my code breaks after it. Is there a way I can tell it to ignore these?

Comment: Assign a "default" category in those cases.

Comment: Is there any other way to ignore these?

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do.  Probably best to ask a new question with the details of your issue, what you tried to fix it and why adding "default" values for category won't work for you.  This isn't really a topic suitable for discussion in the comments.